# WAMP 403 Forbidden message on Windows 8

Tags: php

I have installed WAMP on my windows 8 machine. When i browse to localhost in my browser, the WAMP server page is visible.

But when I browse to my IP in my browser, I get the message

```
403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

i downloaded wamp server from this page
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/

and in C:\wamp\alias phpmyadmin file

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/" 

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#        Order Deny,Allow
#   Deny from all
#   Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#        Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What url do you try to reach? http://[your_ip]/phpmyadmin ?

Comment: We thought you are using other IP. It should simple work without a problem. When you have http://localhost/phpmyadmin in your browser it works?

Comment: its giving the same error i click on icon and then i click on phpmyadmin and i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to make the same changes you made in the phpmyadmin config file to the Apache config file httpd.conf, by default Apache only allows localhost access. Search for httpd.conf and make changes ,I don't know where conf file would be placed by default on Windows box.

Comment: i didnot get what i have to do to solve this problem

Comment: Search your computer for httpd.conf, modify config file in notepad or something, make the same changes you did to the phpmyadmin config file that you posted above, the changes that were commented out in the original phpmyadmin file that you edited. You may need to restart apache, in linux I use apachectl graceful, not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could change :

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
```

into:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from localhost
```

That's in my file. Maybe this will help you. You also didn't say if `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` works fine

But in fact it should work just right after install. If it's not maybe you should try to uninstall wamp and install again.

However if I were you I would consider using another wamp server. I've also used this one but updates are not very often, there are problem with switching php version if you need to do more testing. I recently have moved to http://www.easyphp.org/ and it works very nice, I can switch between php versions without problems and new versions (php/phpmyadmin) appear almost just after release date so I recommend you to test this one.

Comment: i changed this too but its not working so i am reinstalling it